# How to determine the [container] and [key] in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

Several 3rd. party applications (such as "CyberDuck" and "Grive") require a [container] and a [key] in order to access files stored in Google Storage.

I have a Google Developers account (paid) and have created "buckets" (is that the same a "container"?).  I can easily transfer files and directories between my Linux server and Google Storage, but only if I use the official **gsutil** tool.

How do I determine the [container] and [key] in Google Drive?

TIA

Addition: It turns out that a "[container]" is what Google calls a "bucket". However, I am still unclear about the "[key]"

Comment: What third party applications are you referring to? I'm not sure what you mean by "container", but instructions for setting up authentication using a key can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts) in the Google Cloud documentation.

Comment: 3rd. party applications such as "CyberDuck" and "Grive".

Comment: "container" is the same as "bucket".

Comment: Can I use the mentioned authentication for Google Drive?

Comment: I'm less familiar with Google Drive (the consumer file-syncing and storage service) than I am with Google Cloud Storage (the API-driven object store that's largely for developers). It [looks like](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth) pretty similar, but I haven't played around with it at all.

Comment: The instructions that you provided are a good start, but all I got is a JSON *private* key. Where should I place it on Linux? In the current directory? Which is the public key? Is that the same as "Client ID"?